# Internal address of the object in hashCode() method

Tags: garbage-collection, hashcode

According to JavaDoc of `Object.hashCode()` this method returns internal address of the object converting it to integer value.

But Garbage Collector can move the object from one memory segment to another changing it internal address. For example the object can be moved from `Young Generation` to `Old Generation`.

See for example the following command line keys of java.exe:

> -XX:+UseSerialGC
>
> -XX:+UseParallelGC
>
> -XX:+UseParallelOldGC
>
> -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

They determine different algorithms of Garbage Collection.

Does it mean that in this case `Object.hashCode()` will return different values?

Or it will always return value corresponding to initial address of the object?

Comment: what prevents you from testing whether the hashcode stays constant under GC activity or not?

Comment: It looks like I will have to. Unfortunately, there is no API that detects moverment of object from one memory segment to the other. If hash code  will be changed then Hash Tables constructed of such objects would be broken which is not suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the javadoc

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> •Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>   execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>   return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>   comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>   consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>   of the same application.